# Mysql Unique column pairs as A,B or B,A where C is higher

Tags: mysqli

I have this table

```
    id|id_user_send|id_user_receive|date
    -------------------------------------
    0 |    1       |     2         |  2017-04-06
    0 |    2       |     1         |  2017-04-07
    0 |    1       |     4         |  2017-04-07
    0 |    1       |     4         |  2017-04-08
    0 |    4       |     1         |  2017-04-09
    0 |    1       |     2         |  2017-04-10
```

i want only unique couple id_user_send,id_user_receive or id_user_receive,id_user_send where date is higher.

I dont see how get this whit group by or select distinct i try number off combine but not work. Can you just give me a way i want understand not just answer please thank you so much to helper.

edit : for me the couple 1, 4 and 4,1 is same i juste want the higher date

Comment: I have updated my solution after your comments and have a SQL fiddle with sample too, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that will help you to get the max C from the all rows that have A,B or B,A.

Here columns used are ..

- A = sender (**`id_user_send`**)
- B = receiver (**`id_user_receive`**)
- C = day (**`date`**)

**`Explanation:`**

- Query consists of `UNION` of 2 queries
- In `First Query`, tables `T1` and `T2` are rows with sender, receiver, concatenated string (sender,receiver) and their max(day). `WHERE` clause matches the concatenated string (`sr`) with reverse of the same string, this will get all the rows where sender and receiver combination is same i.e. (1-4 and 4-1). Using `CASE..WHEN..END` we can get the row that has max date.
- `Second Query` covers `corner scenarios` rows i.e. rows that one way interactions between sender and receiver AND same sender and receiver.

Sample Data Preparation

```
CREATE TABLE stack(sender int, receiver int, day date);

-- rows with sender:receiver as 1-4 or 4-1 (TWO_WAY INTERACTION)
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(1, 4, TO_DATE('2017-04-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(1, 4, TO_DATE('2017-04-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));

INSERT INTO stack VALUES(4, 1, TO_DATE('2017-02-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(4, 1, TO_DATE('2017-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));

-- rows with sender:receiver as 1-1 or 2-1 (TWO_WAY INTERACTION)
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(1, 2, TO_DATE('2017-06-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(1, 2, TO_DATE('2017-04-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));

INSERT INTO stack VALUES(2, 1, TO_DATE('2017-09-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(2, 1, TO_DATE('2017-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));

-- rows with sender:receiver as 3-6 (CORNER SCENARIO : ONE_WAY INTERACTION)
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(3, 6, TO_DATE('2017-09-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(3, 6, TO_DATE('2017-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));

-- rows with sender:receiver as 7-7 (CORNER SCENARIO : SELF INTERACTION)
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(7, 7, TO_DATE('2017-09-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES(7, 7, TO_DATE('2017-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

**`Sample Data View`**
[image]

**`Query`**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CASE
           WHEN T1.maxDay >= T2.maxDay THEN T1.sender ELSE T2.sender
        END as sender,
        CASE
           WHEN T1.maxDay >= T2.maxDay THEN T1.receiver ELSE T2.receiver
        END as receiver,
        CASE
           WHEN T1.maxDay >= T2.maxDay THEN T1.maxDay ELSE T2.maxDay
        END as maxDay
    FROM
        (SELECT sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver) AS sr, MAX(day) AS maxDay
        FROM stack
        GROUP BY sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver)) T1,
        (SELECT sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver) AS sr, MAX(day) AS maxDay
        FROM stack
        GROUP BY sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver)) T2
    WHERE T1.sr = REVERSE(T2.sr)
UNION
    SELECT T1.sender, T1.receiver, T1.maxday
    FROM
        (SELECT sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver) AS sr, MAX(day) AS maxDay
        FROM stack
        GROUP BY sender, receiver, (sender || ',' || receiver)) T1
    WHERE T1.sr NOT IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT (REVERSE(sender || ',' || receiver))
        FROM stack)
```

**`Result`**
[image]

Let me know if you need more explanation for query.

I have provided SQL Fiddle also for you to play around with the query so you can understand it by executing it part by part.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d6f7/3/0

Comment: thanks but i just want line 4,1 2017-04-09 not  line 1,4 2017-04-08 because date is less than 4,1

Comment: Updated query with your expectations and confirmed behavior through SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d6f7/3/0. Screenshots attached with results.